# Closest circle intersection within a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangulation

*(Context: I use a Delaunay triangulation for pathfinding, and have circular points of interest, of varying sizes, being randomly placed around the map. Units need to be able to determine the closest such point of interest to path to, using a Dijkstra search across the triangulation.)*

Given a triangle, and a set of circles which overlap or intersect it, I'm trying to find the closest circle to a given point within the triangle.

My first thought was to just take the distance from the point to each circle center, minus the radius. But there are some cases where that does not give the correct result. See the following image:

[image]

Measuring from point `P` within the triangle, to circles `A` and `B`. Using only the radius of each circle, as with d<sub>1</sub> and d<sub>2</sub>, would result in circle `A` being considered closest. However, the closest edge of circle `A` used to measure d<sub>1</sub> is outside of the triangle. Staying within the triangle, the closest edge from point `P` to circle `A` would be d<sub>3</sub>, which is much further away than d<sub>2</sub>, indicating that circle `B` is actually closest within the triangle.

Is there a method for determining this difference, finding d<sub>3</sub> for circles where d<sub>1</sub> would be outside the triangle? How do you determine the intersection point between circle `A` and the triangle?

Comment: A might well be the "correct" result, if there's an adjacent triangle we can navigate through to take that shortest path d1. If your agent chooses B, that might reveal the underlying bias of the pathfinding triangulation, which should be invisible to the player as a hidden implementation detail in most games. For distance d3 though, can't you find that with 3 line-versus-circle intersection tests?

Comment: You make a very good point. If the closest circle is outside of the current triangle, I probably need to reject all choices within the current triangle and continue pathing...